# Find all Critical Values for a Function

Tags: calculus

Find all critical values for the function $f(x)=2x^3-27x+108x-1$
I took the derivative, getting $f'(x)=6x^2-54x+108$
I then set the derivative to zero, $6x^2-54x+108=0$
I factored this out, getting the values $x=108$ and $x=216$
This is incorrect, but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: No I did not! Oops, will correct.

Comment: Hmm okay. Guess it's a factoring problem?

Comment: Yes, very clear thank you! Forgot to pull the 6 out of the equation before I used the quadratic formula. So the answer would be 6 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have messed up using the formula for solutions to a quadratic, try this again and show me your working and I'll debug

Comment: I factored wrong, and forgot to simplify by dividing everything in the derivative by 6 before using the quadratic formula. After doing so I came to the correct conclusion that the critical values are 6 and 3.